# Incorrect title of meta mod-message notifications [cake inside! :p]

Tags: bug, moderator-messages

Mod messages on meta show up with a rather odd title on SO: "moderator message on [moderator] added a new reply" instead of e.g. "moderator message on meta"

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshit]

Notifications of messages sent on SO look like this (in the notifications tab):

> [mod] added a new reply
>   [user] added a new reply
>   [mod] added a new message

The lack of message contents is probably intended in the notifications tab, but the very different and very odd title used in case of the meta messages smells like a bug.

---

And here's the delicious thing that caused the message in #JavaScript - yes, you SHOULD feel hungry now:

[image: windows pie]
(source: http://www.heise.de/ct/motive/12/15/)

Comment: Could just eliminate the "moderator message on" wording.  In other news, what is it in the Javascript chat room that I really want to eat?

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Image included. And no, there's no linux version :p

Comment: Yum. . . . . . .